# How do I remove F_01 from the Timeline?

Tags: interface, timeline

My smash into animation triggered this `F_01` thing which might be an *F Curve* somewhere? More importantly than what it is in any detail is getting rid of it.

[image: r]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have accidentally pressed <kbd>M</kbd> on the keyboard while your mouse was hovering over the timeline. These are called [markers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/markers.html) in Blender.

To delete it, select the marker with **left-click** (<kbd>LMB</kbd>), keep your mouse hovered over the marker area, and then press <kbd>X</kbd> then **Delete Markers**.

[image: example]